# How to update and increment a counter in postgresql and mybatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis, spring-data-mybatis

I am using `spring-mybatis` and I am doing this `update`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.test.Article">

    <update resultType="java.lang.Long"  id="updateClickCount" flushCache="true">
        UPDATE "article"
        SET "click_count" = "click_count" + 1
        WHERE "id" = #{id,jdbcType=NUMERIC}
        RETURNING "click_count";
    </update>

</mapper>
```

I expect to be able to read the `count` in the same request as the one that `increment` the `count`.

Instead, it gives me this error:

```java
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 81; Attribute "resultType" must be declared for element type "update".
```

How can I read the update count value in postgrsql and mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an UPDATE...RETURNING statement returns values in a ResultSet. MyBatis only decodes ResultSets in `<select>` statements. So you will need to write your statement as a `<select>`. This will look weird, but will work perfectly fine. The different XML tags don't do any checking to ensure that the included SQL actually matches the tag.

One other thing you will need to think about is that `<select>` statements do not get committed automatically by MyBatis - so you might need to manually commit after the statement executes depending on how you have setup your transaction manager.